# How to deploy an Angular4 + Webpack app on Azure web app without any source repository?

Tags: angular, azure, webpack, azure-web-app-service

I have angular 4 + webpack app which don't want to be checked in to any source repository such as git . I was wondering how i can deploy it to azure web app ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should build your angular4 app locally, if you are using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) you can use the command `ng build` to do that. Next, upload those files located in `dist/` folder to your Azure App Service via FTP.

Check out this post to see how you can publish using FTP:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp